# Is it possible to remove the heap from an ELF Core file?

Tags: c++, linux-kernel, operating-system, stack-trace, elf

I'm collecting stacktraces from very large coredumps via `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern`. The following questions suggest using `/proc/pid/core_filter` to reduce the size of large coredumps:

[Minimal core dump (stack trace + current frame only)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836459/minimal-core-dump-stack-trace-current-frame-only)

[Selective core dump in Linux - How can I select the dumped sections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817867/selective-core-dump-in-linux-how-can-i-select-the-dumped-sections/4818523#4818523)

[Is it possible to get a Linux coredump that only contains callstack, threads, and local variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18911367/is-it-possible-to-get-a-linux-coredump-that-only-contains-callstack-threads-an)

But, when setting core_filter to '0', the resulting coredump is no longer meaningful to gdb's bt command.

So, I have the following two part question:

1) Is there a tool besides gdb which can extract the stacktrace from these minimal coredumps?

2) Is it possible to parse an ELF Core file to remove the heap segments? This question: [What and where are the stack and heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap?lq=1) seems to indicate this might be possible.

Thanks!

Comment: It shouldn't be super difficult to do that. Grab the ELF spec, use `readelf` on some existing core dump files, and see if you can make a selective copy of one that omits the program segments that you don't care about.

Comment: @KerrekSB Sounds good - but, how do I identify which segments I don't care about?

Comment: Well, the program header tells you the virtual address and the size of the segment... does that help?

Comment: @KerrekSB hmmm... locating the segments and the virtual address ranges of the segments is not a problem. My question is, how do I know which segments contain heap data and which contain stack data? Hope that clarifies things. Thanks!

Comment: On my 64-bit system, the heap segments seem to start at "0x00007f2xxxxxxxxx", and the stack is at "0x00007fffxxxxxxxx" -- look for the read-writable pages.

Comment: @KerrekSB I ran readelf on a few cores and it's still not quite clear to me what you mean -- are you saying that the segments with flags RW are the heap? For me, those segments have a wide range of addresses. Would it be possible to provide some more details on what you're doing, possibly as a full answer to the question?

Answer (score 1):

> But, when setting core_filter to '0', the resulting coredump is no longer meaningful to gdb's bt command.

Note that for a dynamically-linked binary, GDB `backtrace` needs to know about all shared libraries that appear in the stack trace (so it can find corresponding unwind descriptors).

For a "normal" core file, this info is in *heap*. Dropping heap from `core` then damages `info shared`, which in turn makes `backtrace` that has any shared libraries non-working.

You may be able to turn off bits 0 and 1 (anonymous private and shared mappings, which would cover heap) and still get a usable core *if* you turn on bit 3 (which would cover text of shared libraries, and which is normally not necessary, but is made necessary by dropping heap).

Comment: Thanks for the info! I tried setting core_filter to 24 (0x18) but the core was still unusable by `gdb bt`. The additional insight was helpful though.

Comment: I found this paper: http://www.researchgate.net/publication/251890419_On_reducing_of_core_dump_file_size which keeps just the program segment of the stack. I'm doubtful though that would work on x86_64 -- what do you think?